# R twitterwidget package - tweet not cleared when shiny input is updated

Tags: r, twitter, shiny, htmlwidgets, twitter-widget

Each time my input to `renderTwitterwidget()` is changed, a new tweet is printed underneath the original tweet on the Shiny UI. Is it possible to clear the old tweet and print a new one each time a new `twitterwidget` object is passed to `renderTwitterwidget`?

Example of the problem:
https://media.giphy.com/media/BQUewH12DzhxX2bjMP/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611692336f45990123a77213a1975b8338b7e69b6e1&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g

**The code doesn't properly render the content using the RStudio viewer, so please use view the app in the browser to check the result.**

This is the code for the shiny app:

```
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(twitterwidget)
library(tidyverse)
library(rtweet)

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Input functions
  textInput(inputId = 'search_term',
            label = 'Search tweets from the last 6-9 days:',
            #value = 'covid',
            placeholder = '#covid-19',
            width = '90%'
  ),
  actionButton(inputId = 'submit_button',
               label = 'Submit'
  ),
  
  # Output functions 
  twitterwidgetOutput('twitter', width = "100%", height = "400px")
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Get data 
  tweet_id <- eventReactive(input$submit_button, {search_tweets(q = input$search_term, n = 1, lang = 'en') %>% pull(status_id)})
 
  # Twitter widget
  output$twitter <- renderTwitterwidget(twitterwidget(tweet_id()))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Code for those without a twitter account:

```
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(twitterwidget)
library(tidyverse)


# Vector of tweet status_id's ---------------------------------------------

v_ids <- c("1434550715905724416", "1434404394133594112", "1434270392533889039", "1432293982541946884", "1432396306698354688",
           "1434187565633003526", "1433095963338551297", "1432339458309955585", "1431909314600574977","1432064144040202241",
           "1434268168231477248", "1431912031100227589", "1434188285103022086", "1432066801588920325", "1434184994579230720",
           "1434100772069908485", "1433887544274563075", "1433801716202344460", "1433799487592468492", "1433754869429592078",
           "1433120347176386561", "1432410673259057161", "1433115345938784263", "1433093342456389639", "1432961860731478017",
           "1432828362280476673", "1432812324709179394", "1432806681793159168", "1432721292403281920", "1432707208211537930",
           "1432700115299586053", "1432658875665289216", "1432623112747638785", "1432614035141312513", "1432612768717451266")

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Input functions
  textInput(inputId = 'search_term',
            label = 'Search tweets from the last 6-9 days:',
            #value = 'covid',
            placeholder = '#covid-19',
            width = '90%'
  ),
  actionButton(inputId = 'submit_button',
               label = 'Submit'
  ),
  
  # Output functions 
  twitterwidgetOutput('twitter', width = "100%", height = "400px")
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Get data 
  tweet_id <- eventReactive(input$submit_button, {sample(v_ids, 1)})
 
  # Twitter widget
  output$twitter <- renderTwitterwidget(twitterwidget(tweet_id()))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to load the package to search tweets, I have `Error in search_tweets: could not find function "search_tweets"` when I run your code

Comment: @bretauv Sorry! The `search_tweets()` function is in the `rtweet` package. I have updated my code

Comment: I need to have a twitter account to use the api so it won't run for me

Comment: Try the code I have added above. Also please view the app in the browser to check the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird functionality, not sure if its an issue with the package or what. You can also just use `shinyjs` and write a user-defined `javascript` function to clear the contents of the `div`.

Here is a brief implementation that should work:

```r
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(twitterwidget)
library(tidyverse)
library(rtweet)

# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(
    text = "shinyjs.refresh = function() {
      var div = document.getElementById('twitter_output');
      while(div.firstChild){
          div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
        }
      }",
    functions = c("refresh")
  ),
  # Input functions
  textInput(
    inputId = 'search_term',
    label = 'Search tweets from the last 6-9 days:',
    #value = 'covid',
    placeholder = '#covid-19',
    width = '90%'
  ),
  actionButton(inputId = 'submit_button',
               label = 'Submit'),
  
  twitterwidgetOutput("twitter_output")
)

# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$submit_button, {
    # Obtain tweet ID
    tweet_id <-
      search_tweets(q = input$search_term,
                    n = 1,
                    lang = 'en') %>%
      pull(status_id)
    
    # Refresh the `twitter_output` div
    shinyjs::js$refresh()
    
    # Render the tweet again.
    output$twitter_output <-
      renderTwitterwidget(twitterwidget(tweet_id))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```